# What is the relation of HOL Light type theory and some of the intuitionistic type theories?

Tags: type-theory, proof-assistants, hol-light, hol

I'm trying to understand how [`HOL Light`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOL_Light#logical_foundations) deductive rules relate to mainstream intuitionistic type theories.
Here is a sample of questions that come to my mind.

Does `HOL Light` derivations admit cut-elimination and what sub-formula property would mean? Is there some kind of canonicity result?

Can HOL equality be modeled with Identity types (with J axiom)?

Somewhat specific question: `DEDUCT_ANTISYM_RULE` axiom allows us to deduce that if you have  (entilement) both $q \vdash p$ and $p \vdash q$, we can deduce $\vdash p=q$. How can we assert that rule without a condition that the entailments are "each other inverses forming an isomorphism"?

I realize that many of these question might be wrong questions to ask. Perhaps I even am wrong to focus on the deduction rules? 
How should I be thinking when comparing theories such as HOL Light and some intuitionistic type theories?

Comment: Regarding the DEDUCT_ANTISYM_RULE of your question, this is what is usually called *propositional extensionality* (and it basically presumes some kind of proof irrelevance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to see HOL as an instance of a "dependent" type theory, in a way that is reasonable, that is there is a *pure type system* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_type_system) $\mathrm{\lambda HOPL}$ which contains an embedding

$$ [\!| \_\mid\!] :\mathrm{HOL}\rightarrow \mathrm{\lambda HOPL}$$

Which is both *sound* and *complete*, that is:

$$\Gamma\vdash_{\mathrm{HOL}}P\quad \mbox{iff}\quad [\!|\Gamma|\!]\vdash_{\mathrm{\lambda HOPL}} [\!| P|\!]$$

But this is *without* any axioms, in particular without $$\mathrm{PROPEXT}: (P \leftrightarrow Q)\ \rightarrow\ P=Q$$ for every $P$ and $Q$.

This is explained in some detail by Tonino and Fujita in [On the adequacy of representing higher order intuitionistic logic as a pure type system](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800729290044Z). I think the proof can also be found in Herman Geuvers' dissertation, but I'm a bit lazy to check at the moment.

With PROPEXT, this stops being true, I believe, *however*, the rule
$$ (P\leftrightarrow Q)\quad \rightarrow\quad C\ P \rightarrow C\ Q$$

is *admissible* for any *closed* predicate transformer $C:\mathrm{Prop}\rightarrow\mathrm{Prop}$, by a pretty straightforward induction on (normal forms of) $C$, so in some weaker sense, PROPEXT is justified in such a system (we can define equality to be $P=Q\ :=\ \forall C, C\ P \rightarrow C\ Q$).

Note that this breaks down if you identify $\mathrm{Prop}$ and $\mathrm{Type}$, as explained by Geuvers in [The Calculus of Constructions and Higher Order Logic](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2756/587b1fbb97001aa3f23eec5f4d4ad93ef1a7.pdf) (i.e. CoC with this axiom is not conservative over HOL). In *this* sense, PROPEXT is not justified by the Martin-Löf propositions-as-types viewpoint.

I think you can form a similar story with the $J$-axiom. I'm not certain equality reflection needs to come into it, since you don't have that many dependent shenanigans resulting from the embedding.

In response to your other questions:

- There is definitely some kind of canonicity result, which gets more subtle as you add classical axioms. Certainly the axiom-free system with only the $\forall$, $\rightarrow$ and equality rules admits cut-elimination.
- I'm less sure about the sub-formula properties, but I'm pretty sure they hold in the usual manner, once one has correctly formulated them in the higher order setting. They're a bit less satisfying though, since one may need to take instances of formulae quantifying over propositions themselves. I don't see a lot of use for such theorems in the meta-theory of HOL.

Answer (score 2):

HOL is a [simple type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-church/), while Martin-Löf's is a *dependent* type theory. That is the fundamental difference between the two.

One can embed HOL into *extensional* type theory, i.e., type theory with identity types and the equality reflection principle
$$\frac{\vdash p : \mathrm{Id}_A(s,t)}{\vdash s \equiv_A t}$$
You could try a less drastic principle, such as Streicher's $K$ axiom or uniqueness of identity proofs, in which case you will be interested in conservativity of intensional type theory with $K$ over extensional type theory. But perhaps you don't want to dig into such details right now.

Comment: Section 5 of [The HOL Light manual](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/manual-1.1.pdf) indeed affirms that the basis of HOL Light it a simple type theory.

Comment: What do we require from the extensional type theory to make the embedding work? You pointed out existence of identity types and equality reflection principle. Nit: does it make a difference if we add a constant $r : Id_T (\lambda x.t x\;,\; t)$ or assert that equality definitionally (Indeed let's ignore the finesse of K)?  Importantly, how do we interpret HOL 'bool' type? Perhaps as the universe, or should we need to add a Prop type? Could and should 'Hilbert choice operator' and 'ind' type be just defined as constant?

Comment: You can interpret `bool` as `bool` (the inductive type with two constants). Equality reflection implies the $\eta$-law that you're asking about. You can even throw in other forms of extensionality, such as function extensionality, as equlity reflection is very powerful.